# iframed ASP actions trouble

Tags: asp.net

This is actually a follow up on my previous question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944513/getting-a-webresponse-stream-into-iframe-trouble/944597#944597))

I've created the HttpHandler and it works fine for now, I'll add flexibility by using the querystring and session to point the post I'm making in the right direction.

The next question is as follows. 
Now that I have the old page iframed as it should be, there's still the trouble of handling the postbacks (or actions) these pages trigger. 
Every button action (asp form post) refers to a page that is not there (it's on the other server from which I am importing functionality).

I've tried using a url mapping to the other server but I get an error that tells me the external link is not a valid virtual directory. Hence I discarded this option.

I there anyway to keep functionality going inside the iframe?

please do ask clarification if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution from a colleague.

before passing the response string to the Iframe from the handler I use a string.replace to adjust the urls in the old site. This way they point to the old site and everything works again :)